# Unusual looking characters at a temple in Hong Kong?

Tags: characters, pronunciation

[image: Tsz Shan Monastery]

([source](https://www.google.com/maps/@22.4736067,114.2063175,3a,75y,224.64h,128.18t/data=!3m11!1e1!3m9!1sAF1QipOJ9qtg7_NzbRLPCzabL5aJz-PlMUz4WEMKQpg!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOJ9qtg7_NzbRLPCzabL5aJz-PlMUz4WEMKQpg%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya96.94653-ro-0-fo100!7i8704!8i4352!9m2!1b1!2i48))

It's from the Tsz Shan Monastery in the New Territories in Hong Kong.  And I reading it up-down, left-right, or simply left to right on both levels?  Many thanks to whoever can help.

Answer (score 2):

[一生補處](https://www.easyatm.com.tw/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E7%94%9F%E8%A3%9C%E8%99%95)

> 故“一生補處”，乃階地不退轉，功德不斷增長至成佛道之意。
>
> Therefore 'one life make up' means 'accumulate your good deed and merit in this stage (alive as a human) of existence, and eventually achieve enlightenment'